# How to change Pact Broker Context Path?

Tags: pact

We are using pactfoundation/pact-broker image of version 2.93.X.X or higher.

We want to change the context path of the pact broker. In documentation, it is mentioned to set PACT_BROKER_BASE_URL environment variable to change the context path.

When we are using the below properties:

```
PACT_BROKER_PORT=<CUSTOMER_PORT_NUMBER>
PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_URL=<DB_URL>
PACT_BROKER_BASE_URL=http://<COMPANY_DOMAIN>:<CUSTOMER_PORT_NUMBER>/pactbroker
```

And trying to access *http://<COMPANY_DOMAIN>:<CUSTOMER_PORT_NUMBER>/pactbroker* below is the error message we are receiving,

```
404 Not Found    
The requested document was not found on this server.    
Webmachine-Ruby/1.6.0 server
```

*NOTE: When we are not using PACT_BROKER_BASE_URL environment variable then everything is working fine. But we what to change the context path. How can we achieve that?*

Answer (score 0):

The broker itself is not aware of a context path, this is the responsibility of a web server (e.g. nginx or Apache). The base URL property is used in conjunction with however you are running the broker.

If you want to run it on a different context path, you'll need to configure your web server.

See also
https://docs.pact.io/pact_broker/configuration/features#running-the-broker-behind-a-reverse-proxy

Comment: Hi Mathew Fellows, Thanks for your response. But I am new to this, can you please tell me how can I change the web server configuration of the pact broker docker image?

Comment: To answer that question we would need to know how you're running and deploying the pact broker and its configuration, which is well outside of the scope of the project. The question you need to ask is about the web server you use (whatever that is) and how to proxy an application at a different context path.

Comment: I am not using any specific web server for this, I am just using the default pactfoundation/pact-broker docker images and passing the environment variables as mentioned.  If I do not use PACT_BROKER_BASE_URL then everything works fine for me. But when I configure PACT_BROKER_BASE_URL it gives me 404 error. So how can I make it working with PACT_BROKER_BASE_URL

Comment: That's not what those environment variables do. If you want a different context path you'll need a web server

Comment: It will be helpful if you have any reference for how can we run pact broker docker image with web server?

Comment: If you don't need to run it behind a web server, then don't. Why do you actually need the context path to be different? The only time this makes sense to do is when it is run on a webserver on a different path, to avoid clashes with another path.

Comment: There is an ALB (Load balance) and I have kept the setting as whenever ALB receives a request at /pactbroker forward the request to the container where my docker image of the pact is running. But when I try to access the pact broker UI it gives me 404 error ("404 Not Found    The requested document was not found on this server.    
Webmachine-Ruby/1.6.0 server").

Comment: You should read up on path based routing for AWS ALB v2. Your ALB should respond to `/pactbroker` but should forward to `/` at the container. It's getting a 404 because you're likely not removing the path prefix. If you do this, you must bring back the PACT_BROKER_BASE_URL env var

Comment: I am using PACT_BROKER_BASE_URL env var when my ALB is listening to /pact broker and fowarding the request to pact broker docker container. But its give 404. Anything more changes I need to do for making it work?